# Compare <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>, str and datetime64[ns] dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I need to query using dates of various data types, the data and their corresponding data types are listed below:

```
last_month_year: <class 'str'> ** Used `pd.to_datetime()` and got `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` format
current_month_year: <class 'str'>
df['Year_Month']: object
```

The query:

```
df[(df['Year_Month'] == current_month_year) | (df['Year_Month'] == last_month_year)]
```

The dates consist of "year" and "month" and are of the format "Year_Month", e.g., `"2020-01"`.

I had a few attempts at converting them into the same data type but there are always certain issues. What's the best data type to convert these three data types into to compare them? Thanks.

Comment: Whats the datatype of `Year_Month` series? Is it `str`? How is `last_month_year` calculated?

Comment: Hi @Ashyam, `Year_Month` is an object, `last_month_year` is calculated as: `last_month_year_time = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-12)
last_month_year = last_month_year_time.strftime("%Y-%m")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both `'Year_Month'` column and `current_month_year` to `datetime64[ns]` type using the [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method

```py
df['Year_Month'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Month'])
current_month_year = pd.to_datetime(current_month_year)

out = df[(df['Year_Month'] == current_month_year) | (df['Year_Month'] == last_month_year)]
```

Comment: Hi Jamius, thanks for your answer. However, `pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Month'])` incurred error `TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime`, so I tried `pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Month'], errors='coerce')` but it renders all `df['Year_Month']` values to `NaT`